# mongoose.js 3: how to tell that nested is not a document

Tags: mongoose

My mongoose Schema:

```
mongoose.Schema({
        title: 'string',
        items: [{
            uid: 'string',
            type: {type: 'string'},
            title: 'string',
            items: [{uid: 'string', type: {type: 'string'}, text: 'string'}]
        }]
    });
```

How to tell mongoose that items (and items of items) are not documents, but just nested objects? I need neither the `_id` property nor any document's functionality for them, but I want to define them and restrict with schema.

Is `_id: false` is enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embedded document arrays without their own schema (like you show above) will always have an `_id` field.  If you want to suppress the `_id` they have to have their own schema and you need to set the `{ _id: false }` [option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) on their schema definition.

```js
mongoose.Schema({
    title: 'string',
    items: [mongoose.Schema({
        uid: 'string',
        type: {type: 'string'},
        title: 'string',
        items: [mongoose.Schema({
            uid: 'string', 
            type: {type: 'string'}, 
            text: 'string'
        }, {_id: false})]
    }, {_id: false})]
});
```