# mongoose field with the name type

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to validate and save a Passport profile with this structure:

http://passportjs.org/guide/profile/

This is the scheme I came up with:

```
// Define the schema.
schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // The name of this user, suitable for display.
    displayName: String,
    // Each e-mail address ...
    emails: [{
        // ... with the actual email address ...
        value: String,
        // ... and the type of email address (home, work, etc.).
        type: String
    }],
    // A unique identifier for the user, as generated by the service provider.
    id: String,
    // The name ...
    name: {
        // ... with the family name of this user, or "last name" in most Western languages ...
        familyName: String,
        // ... with the given name of this user, or "first name" in most Western languages ...
        givenName: String,
        // ... and with the middle name of this user.
        middleName: String
    },
    // The provider which with the user authenticated.
    provider: String
});
```

The e-mail has a property called 'type', which is reserved for a mongoose type. How do I solve this?

Comment: docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#type-key

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You need to define the field using an object:

```
type: {type: String}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer when the time limit allows me to. An unrelated question, the e-mail array now has an _id field which I don't want. Is there a quick/easy fix too?

Comment: @RoelvanUden See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617754/mongoose-js-3-how-to-tell-that-nested-is-not-a-document/12621311#12621311

Comment: To disable the auto _id, just add '_id: false' to the object: emails: [{
        _id: false,
        value: String,
        type: { type: String }
    }],

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Mongoose 4+**

You have to define the `typeKey` to the schema.

```
const schema = new Schema({
    //Define a field called type of type String
    type: { $type: String },
    //Define a field called whatever of type Array
    whatever: { $type: Array }
}, { typeKey: '$type' });
```

So all the schema will use the keyword `$type` to set the type of the field. And you can safely use `type` to set the name of the field.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey