# fieldname "type" in my schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a really strange situtation; my schema has a fieldname which is called "type"

```
type: { type: String, default:"article" }
```

the schema is extended by subclasses which override the type field name to change the default value

when I create the document and directly after the cb fires, find it and output the result to console.log, I see "type" and the value "article" set as its value within the object.

when I access it with the mongo client, there is no field called "type". Getting just the type also doesn't show any document that have that field using this command

```
db.clouds.find({},{type:1}).pretty();
```

in a other script (that executes later), I get the document with mongoose again and there is also no "type" field there either.

Is "type" some special no-no word? My schema worked fine since ages and stopped working recently.

Thanks for your help
MongoDB: 2.4.9
Mongoose: 3.8.5

/edit, updated with real schema. My schema worked for a year until recently.

```
var Cloud = new Schema({
    type        :{ type:String, required:true },
    children    :[ { type:ObjectId } ], //Cloud ID
    value       :{ type: String, max:1024, default:function(){return "SomeRandomString" + Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000) } },
    cats:[ {type: ObjectId} ]       
},
{
    collection:"clouds"
});


//make sure Mongooose provides the fields correctly;
Cloud.set('toJSON', { getters: true, virtuals: false } );
```

and subclassing like this (in another file, including the above file, thus making a new schema defininition)

```
var ArticleCloud=Cloud;
ArticleCloud.add(
{
    type: { type: String, default:"article" },
    url         :{ type: String , index: true },
    state: {type: Number, default: config.err[500].code, index: true },
    weight:{type: Number, index:true}

}
);
```

Comment: Actually correct JSON notation requires the keys to be quoted. So use "type" instead

Comment: @NeilLunn There isn't any JSON in the question. It's discussing defining Mongoose `Schema`s in JavaScript, where Object keys can also be specified as identifiers.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `Schema({ "type": {  }})` sure looks like JSON notation to me. It's also the answer to the question as `type` has not been quoted here as I have. Quote it and it works

Comment: @NeilLunn They're similar, yes, because JSON's syntax was taken from JavaScript's syntax for literals and initializers (that's why JSON's full name begins with "JavaScript"). But, JSON is just data, not code. It isn't executed. And, the inclusion of `Schema()`, a custom type, is only possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. I've tried it with the quotes before and it doesn't change the result. As Jonathan points out, its objectliterals and mongodb uses BSON, so this is correct (and as mongoose has its in the docs and answered here; http://stackoverflow.com/a/15100043/809423). Please don't fight

Comment: @japrescott Can you edit your question to include your full schema definition?

Comment: The simple cases of using `type` fields seem to work fine in Mongoose 3.8.9.  It's likely related to how you're subclassing the schema and overriding `type`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I updated my answer with the real (truncated) schema. As the schema worked for a long time, I can't imagine it has anything todo with this, but thank you for looking at it

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to do.  `Cloud` and `ArticleCloud` refer to the same object so this isn't subclassing.  Anyway, I think you're going to have to provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem as it's working when I try it.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I am aware of that. But I cant post my code in the entire form, obviously. Both schemas are in separate files, and I require each when I need them, thus creating 2 different Schemas based on the same "base-class". But maybe my term "subclassing" is wrong.

Comment: Anyway, I managed to get it to work again, when I specifically state the type when creating the document, it is present but not, when I rely on the 'default' property.