# Mongoose - is it possible to use parameters in mongo query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, increment, mongodb-query

I've found how to update in mongoose with [this guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html).

I want to increase a field, but the problem is: I want to get that field name in run-time.

in other words - I want to send **type** parameter and in runtime so it'll increase the relevant field (counter1 \ counter2).

is it possible??

```
var conditions = {_id:post},
update = { $inc: { counterType: 1 }},
options = {multi:false},
callback = function(err,numAffected){ if (err) console.log(err);}
    
Post.update(conditions,update,options,callback);
```

where **Post** is pre-defined as a Schema:

```
var Post = new Schema({
    post : String,
    user :String, 
    counter1:Number,
    counter2:Number,
    counterType:String
});
```

so if I call this function when ***counterType = counter1***

the wanted result should be ***counter1*** field incremented by 1 in the DB.

my problem is that it looks for "counterType" instead of the value in it (***counter1***)

Comment: Did you try it? What did you get?

Comment: it looks for "type" instead of the type value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongoose field with the name type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100013/mongoose-field-with-the-name-type)

Comment: Really only asking you (initial comment) to please clearly state what your intent and problem is. People should not need to read through comments to work that out. Edit your question please.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, it's not a duplicate of the link you gave. the problem is not with "type" being a save word, but on those query objects like { $inc: { type: -1 }} it's being transferred hard-coded. I changed it to "counterType" in the example to make it clearer. thanks.

Comment: Don't know how the comments are appearing out of order, but quite clearly you need to explain what is the problem as I initially asked. Show an error or erroneous result.

Comment: You can't use the value of one field (`counterType`) as the name of another field (`'counter1'`) in an update.  If that's what you're trying to do it won't work.