# Pushing a hash to a nested array with Mongoose & Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In the below user schema there is a `foobar.events` field, an *array of hashes*, that I am trying to push new hashes (that are received from an API POST request) to.

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    foobar: {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String,
        events       : [{
            action          : String,
            timestamp       : Date,
            user_xid        : String,
            type            : {type: String},
            event_xid       : String    
        }]
    }

});
```

And here is the logic for that Express route:

```
app.post('/foobar/post', function(req, res) {
    var jb_user_xid  = req.body['events'][0]['user_xid'];
    var jb_timestamp = req.body['events'][0]['timestamp'];
    var jb_action    = req.body['events'][0]['action'];
    var jb_type      = req.body['events'][0]['type'];
    var jb_event_xid = req.body['events'][0]['event_xid'];

    User.findOne({'foobar.id':jb_user_xid}, function(err, user) {
        user.foobar.events.push({
            user_xid: jb_user_xid,
            timestamp: jb_timestamp,
            action: jb_action,
            type: jb_type,
            event_xid: jb_event_xid
        });
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err){ 
                console.log("Error on save: " + err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Save successful");
            }
        });
    });

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
    return;
});
```

The `find` and `save` execute successfully, but the hash itself isn't saved to the database, as shown in the logfile:

```
Mongoose: users.update({ _id: ObjectId("53f7d23e432de20200970c10") }) { '$inc': { __v: 1 }, '$pushAll': { 'foobar.events': [ '[object Object]' ] } } {}
```

And here is what the entry looks like within MongoLab:

```
{
    "__v": 11,
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53f7d23e432de202970c10"
    },
    "foobar": {
        "events": [
            "[object Object]",
            "[object Object]",
            "[object Object]",
            "[object Object]",
            "[object Object]"
        ],
        "id": "aguxwNqb_Xg87buMWiw",
        "name": "Test User",
        "token": "W3AjaI7_iOWilcKRpmx"
    }
}
```

**Question:** How do I save the actual contents from the API hash to a new hash within the `foobar.events` array?

As a side note, this is what is returned in `req.body` from the API:

```
{  events:
    [ { action: 'updation',
        timestamp: 1408846680,
        user_xid: 'aguxwNqb_Xg87buMyP6Wiw',
        type: 'move',
        event_xid: 'vhAkgg1XwQvLynAkkCc8Iw' } ],
   notification_timestamp: 1408846680 }
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. What exactly do you want to do with the hash (you mean `secret_hash` right?).

Comment: Sorry, `secret_hash` is actually irrelevant

Comment: I want the contents of `events` (updation, move, etc) within the API response to be saved to a hash within the `foobar.events` array

Comment: Have you tried logging the contents of the document otherwise -- `console.log("Save successful", user.foobar.events);`? Mongoose may just not be showing the details of the document beyond a certain depth to avoid infinite recursion from circular references or just to keep the log entry somewhat short. The `'[object Object]'` listed would be the `.toString()` of the `Object`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski logging the contents results in `Save successful ["[object Object]"]`. I also updated the question with the actual entry within MongoLab, which shows the same result as on the Mongoose log

Comment: @Anconia The issue is the `type: String` property. Because of it, Mongoose thinks the Object is a SchemaType definition, defining an `Array` of `String`s rather than an `Array` of sub-documents. [It needs to be defined as `type: { type: String }` to remove the ambiguity.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100013/mongoose-field-with-the-name-type)