# Storing a JSON object in Mongoose / MongoDB which is declared as a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, mongoose-schema

Trying to store a JSON object in Mongoose and saving it within the database is getting some problems for me,
here is an example of the code I am using.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: randomlyGeneratedIDGoesHere,
  subInfoData: [
    {
  _id: Number,
  name: String,
  type: String,
    },
  ],
});

const Model = mongoose.model("example", Schema);

infoData = await Model.findOne({ _id: specificIDGoesHereThisIsJustToShowcase });

subInfoData = {
  _id: randomlyGeneratedIDGoesHere,
  name: "none",
  type: "example",
};
infoData.subInfoData.push(subInfoData);
infoData.save();
```

However when the data is stored it is stored in a fashion similar to this:

`subInfoData : ["1004456331861831750", "1004466251483074582"]`

I have been in quite a few places and cannot seem to get this to work, anyone know what might be wrong or any solutions there might be for this?

**EDIT**
After some digging I am even more perplexed:

Using

```
await infoData.subInfoData.push({
  _id: RandomStringHere,
  nickname: "none",
  });
```

Only seems to store

```
[RandomStringHere]
```

I am absolutely bewildered and complexed as to how this does not work.

Comment: Remove the `_id` declarations and assignments . mongoose inserts those automatically for you.

Comment: The "_id" is generated by my application to find it back again, it is essential for the programs functionality and is not the issue due to the fact it is also used within other parts of my application without any issue, is there any chance it might be something else?

Comment: Noticed now that you have a property `type`. type is a reserved word in mongoose. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100013/mongoose-field-with-the-name-type)

Comment: That is actually a really good find, should've thought of that before, I will check and see if that might be a cause of any underlying issues, however it wouldn't define why Mongoose only stores the "_id" part of the entire collection that is pushed, is there any other idea as to how or why this would happen in the first place?

Comment: Nevermind, I stand corrected, looks like the "type" was indeed an issue, will be forwarding a pull request on Mongoose to at least error it out instead of ignoring the rest of the collection or for there to be a notification when it happens.

Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As user ISAE suggested the issue might be due to the fact I had used a property called "type" within the model, Mongoose does not log any issues or the fact that the type itself may be invalid, however that was indeed the issue in this instance.

All credit goes to ISAE for the fix, hope any future people here may find this useful if they require help.